# Validation in FubuMvc 1.0

Tags: fubumvc

I'm new using FubuMvc, I recently Update to version 1.0 which doesn't have any documentation and it seems like there's a lot of breaking changes in the code, I'm trying to understand how the validation rules and validation in general works in fubu.

I can't find the validation method even If I import FubuMVC.Validation

```
this.Validation(x => { 
    x....
});
```

is there any new approach for this, I just would like to have clear the concept of how the validation occurs in fubu.

Can I apply a convention for validation?
Example: to all my Entities that contain a field named "email" apply a regex validation with a standard formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new FubuMVC.Validation bottle is completely drop-in and doesn't require much configuration at all. If you want to configure the chains it applies to, simply do:

AlterSettings(x => ...); <--- in your FubuRegistry

Right *now*, we don't do conventional validation that way out-of-the-box. You have two ways:

1. Attributes
2. The OverridesFor DSL in FubuMVC.

Examples of both of those can be found here (respectively):

1. https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/fubuvalidation/blob/master/src/FubuMVC.Validation.StoryTeller/User.cs
2. https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/fubuvalidation/blob/master/src/FubuMVC.Validation.StoryTeller/AccessorOverridesModel.cs

**That being said...**

Anything that implements IFieldValidationSource gets automatically registered into your container. This is how we convert from OverridesFor to rules, for example:

https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/fubuvalidation/blob/master/src/FubuMVC.Validation/AccessorRulesFieldSource.cs

So you could reflect on that property and return an EmailFieldRule. Something like this:

https://gist.github.com/4540861

Hope this helps,

Josh

Comment: lets sat that I'd like to stick to option number 2 and implement OverridesFor<T> which I see that's works similar to fluent validations in asp-mvc, how I can do the wireup for that validation? using  AlterSettings<ValidationSettings>(x => x.Remotes.Include<T>()); will ask to me to implement IFieldValidationRule

Comment: Anything implementing IValidationRegistration get registered automatically.


https://github.com/DarthFubuMVC/fubuvalidation/blob/master/src/FubuMVC.Validation/ValidationRegistrationActivator.cs

We have an adapter for the OverridesFor<T> class implementations so it just gets picked up during app start up.

Comment: On a side note, I'm actually writing the validation documentation right now.